# Regression with xmgrace in param file

Tags: regression, xmgrace

I am trying to write a param file for xmgrace which makes a linear regression, using the command `regress(setnum,order)` but I can't figure out how to make the regression in a given region.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please have a look at [the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour). You may also want to check [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [The perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/), and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Post the code you have tried and the errors you have received. Be as specific as possible as it will lead to better answers.

Comment: Please post what you have so far. Before you can use a "Region" you have to define it. Have you managed to do that successfully in your batch file?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do this would be to make a second input data file that only contains the subset. You can use this subset to calculate the linear regression then plot the resulting line against the original data set. You can hide the data points of the subset.